# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid when trying to use Reflection in F#

Tags: reflection, f#

I am trying to construct a record type in F#. But the following code is giving  `System.InvalidCastException`. I am new to F# and having a difficult time understanding as to why this isn't working. A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type Employee = {
    Id:          Guid
    Name:        string
    Phone:       string
    BadgeId:     string
    Designation: string
}

let values =
    [
        "bc07e94c-b376-45a2-928b-508b888802c9"
        "A"
        "B"
        "C"
        "D"
    ]
    |> Seq.ofList

let creator = FSharpValue.PreComputeRecordConstructor(typeof<Employee>, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)

let x =
    (
        creator [|
            values
            |> Seq.map (fun y -> y)
        |]

    ) :?> Employee

printfn "%A" x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, your record expects a value of type `Guid`, but you are giving it a guid as a string. You can fix this by boxing everyting in your `values` list:

```
let values =
    [
        box (Guid("bc07e94c-b376-45a2-928b-508b888802c9"))
        box "A"
        box "B"
        box "C"
        box "D"
    ]
```

The second issue is that you call `creator` with an array containing a sequence as an argument (there is an extra wrapping). You need to give it array containing the values:

```
let emp = creator (Array.ofSeq values) :?> Employee
```

Comment: I had another question. What if any of the fields were optional? Like option<string>, how would that work?

Comment: @Robur_131 If the fields were of type `option<string>` then the values you specify in your list would have to be of the same type. That is `box (Some("hello"))` for a present value. For missing value, this gets trickier, because you need to specify a type for this to work - so you would need `box (None : option<string>)`

Comment: I have quite similar issue, but values coming from DB using SQLProvider, and I don't understand where I should cast my type to Gudi.

Comment: @ArtemGalas I think you can use `unbox`.

Comment: @Robur_131 thanks for suggestion, but I'm not sure where to put it, you could check my SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/74254183/3933346