# SQLProvider Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'

Tags: f#, mysql-connector

I'm using SQLProvider for making a query in F# project. In my DB I have a column which is storing GUID - `'Id' char(36) NOT NULL`. And when query is made I got an error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
```

I'm using MySqlConnector as a driver.

Here is how table looks in DB

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Comics` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `Price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Image` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Here is types which was generated based on DB

[image]

Here is a query

```
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
let ComicsTable = ctx.ComicsShop.Comics;

let getById (id: string) =
  query {
      for c in ComicsTable do
      where (c.Id = id)
      select c.Id
  } |> Seq.head
```

And usage

```
let result =
    getById "0e49d94e-76c4-44be-b2ea-38382b297c78"

Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: When you hover the cursor over the id parameter for getById, what type do you see?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Full error: `Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: @JimFoye `id: string` c.Id string as well

Comment: Please explitly type all arguments (`id`) before posting, especially in an issue which is all about types. By not doing this you are making users solve a difficult problem (what the inferred type of `id` should be) before starting to tackle your question.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie Thanks, updated question with all type info, what I have

Comment: Could you also post the sql table definition? If I am right it is just a simple type mismatch. The type of the id column in your code should be Guid instead of string because of this your getById function need to cast the string to guid to work.  where (c.Id = (guid id))

Comment: @TorbenClasen added SQL table definition as well. I could't use `Guid id` in the query, as this would be type mismatch, as c.Id is string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite some time of investigation the issue was with DB.
My `Id` field has type as `char(36)` which is converted into string. But since that column contains GUID, SQLProvider will make a query assuming that field is Guid, and it will throw an error in Runtime.
The solutions is simple enough `Id` columns which is containing Guid should be typed as `varchar(36)` then all types will be converted correctly.